# Lubridate get date of certain day in week()

Tags: r, lubridate

I have dates in a dataframe column formatted as character strings like `09/30/2014`

I use `lubridate` to identify the weeks that my dates belong to:

```
library(lubridate)
week(mdy("09/30/2014")
```

gives me the week `40`

I group by that week and aggregate my data. Now I want to turn that week back into a date.
So how can I get the date of a certain day in that week?

`Monday` for example of `Week 40` in `2014` would be the date `09/29/3014`. So I would want to set every `Week 40` to that date.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do the following for example:

```
## 2 for Tuesday ,39 week number, 2014 the year
as.Date("2-39-2014",'%u-%W-%Y')
"2014-09-30"
```

Where you have :

```
> %u :Weekday as a decimal number (1–7, Monday is 1).
> %W :Week of the year as decimal number (00–53) using Monday as the first day of week
> %Y :Year with century.
```